# Access Text Field & Button of any webpage with java

Tags: javascript, java, html, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

I would like to access any input element on webpage with the help of java.

For example:- lets user has opened any website which contains 2text field & 1 text area and submit button.
So what I want is that, all that field should get typed by my java programs.

I have speech to text converter and it works fine.
So what I want is that if user open a site T would like to type some content then by speaking it self that content should get types on the web page.

Say for example,
Post on facebook.
Search friend on facebook.
Querying text on google without query string, means text must get types on browser and user must realize that text is getting typed as he is speaking.

Answer (score 0):

It is a wrong approach to use java or javascript here, you need to modify the browser itself, for example you can check

https://wiki.mozilla.org/SpeechAPI

Comment: I just want that user can access text fields and buttons of webpage with the help of speech. And to hack browser is quit tough task as user can use any browser. If there is another solutions with you then please provide, it will help me a lot else will go with browser hacking